# How to set Check attribute for a radio element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a quiz app using JavaScript and jQuery, if I click on a radio button am setting an attribute as checked but if I move on to another question and click on any radio button there in the previous question radio button selects get removed how can I make sure that it is selected even if I move on to any question and select options there. I guess its happening because I have common name on the radio button Can someone help me out?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    var data = [{
        "id": 1,
        "question": "Which framework is best?",
        "options": ["ReactJs", "AngularJs", "Vue.js", "Backbone"],
        "correctanswer": "ReactJs",
        "selectedanswer": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "question": "What does MVC stands for?",
        "options": ["Model View Controller", "Model view view Controller", "Model Controller view", "None of the above"],
        "correctanswer": "Model View Controller",
        "selectedanswer": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "question": "Which is the best MOOC course website?",
        "options": ["Coursera", "EDX", "Udacity", "Code School"],
        "correctanswer": "Udacity",
        "selectedanswer": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "question": "which backend framework is not available in any of the MOOC site?",
        "options": ["Ruby on Rails", "Node JS", "Metor Js", "Django"],
        "correctanswer": "Django",
        "selectedanswer": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "question": "Which frontend framework is not available?",
        "options": ["AngularJs", "ReactJs", "Backbone", "Knockout"],
        "correctanswer": "ReactJs",
        "selectedanswer": ""
      }
    ];
    var constructordata = function(data) {
      this.id = data.id,
        this.question = data.question,
        this.options = data.options,
        this.correctanswer = data.correctanswer,
        this.selectedanswer = data.selectedanswer
    };
    var datas = [];
    data.forEach(function(item) {
      datas.push(new constructordata(item));
    });
    var controller = {
      nextquestion: function() {
        var currentelement = $('#app .questionsection.visible');
        var nextelement = currentelement.next();
        if (nextelement.hasClass('questionsection')) {
          currentelement.removeClass('visible');
          nextelement.addClass('visible');
        }
        if (!nextelement.next().hasClass('questionsection')) {
          $("button").addClass('visible');
        }
      },
      previousquestion: function() {
        var currentelement = $('#app .questionsection.visible');
        var previouselement = currentelement.prev();
        if (previouselement.hasClass('questionsection')) {
          currentelement.removeClass('visible');
          previouselement.addClass('visible');
        }
      },
      selectanswers: function(temp) {
        for (var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
          if (datas[i].id == temp) {
            datas[i].selectedanswer = $('input[name=optradio]:checked').val();
          }
        }
      },
      checkanswers: function() {
        var score = 0;
        datas.forEach(function(item) {
          if (item.selectedanswer == item.correctanswer) {
            score++;
          }
        });
        console.log(score);
      },
      init: function() {
        view.init();
      }
    };
    var view = {
      init: function() {
        this.maintemplate = $("#app");
        this.nextarrow = $("#next");
        this.submit = $("button");
        this.submit.on('click', function() {
          controller.checkanswers();
        })
        this.nextarrow.on('click', function() {
          controller.nextquestion();
        });
        this.previousarrow = $("#previous");
        this.previousarrow.on('click', function() {
          controller.previousquestion();
        });

        this.render();
      },
      render: function() {
        var maintemplate = this.maintemplate;
        for (var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
          maintemplate.append("<div class='questionsection'><p>" + datas[i].question + "</p></div>");
          for (var j = 0; j < datas[i].options.length; j++) {
            var options = "<div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='optradio' questionno=" + datas[i].id + " value=" + datas[i].options[j] + ">" + datas[i].options[j] + "</label></div>"
            maintemplate.children('.questionsection').last().append(options);
          }
        }
        maintemplate.children().first().addClass('visible');
        var radio = $("input[name=optradio]");
        radio.on('click', function() {
          var temp = $(this).attr("questionno");
          controller.selectanswers(temp);
          $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
        });
      }
    };
    controller.init();
  });
});
```

```css
.questionsection {
  display: none;
}

.btn {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
}

i.fa {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <i id="previous" class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="app" class="col-md-8">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <i id="next" class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn">Submit</button>
</div>
```

CodePen http://codepen.io/kannant14/pen/peLOXG

Comment: *"I guess its happening because i have common name on the radio button"* Right. So...don't do that, use a common name only for the radio buttons related to the same question.

Comment: Yes i have appeneded name with id now its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve it is to name your radiobuttons in the render function with a question index like:

```
var options="<div class='radio'><label><input type='radio' name='optradio"+i+"' questionno="+datas[i].id+" value="+datas[i].options[j]+">"+datas[i].options[j]+"</label></div>"
```

and the same in the selectanswers function:

```
selectanswers:function(temp) {          
  for(var i=0;i<datas.length;i++) {
    if(datas[i].id==temp){
      datas[i].selectedanswer=$('input[name=optradio'+i+']:checked').val();
    }
  }
}
```

then you just need to keep track of the question index when checking the correct answers.